# Get html code of erb template in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have `home_controller` and there are  `[:index, :process_img]` actions within.
I need to get the whole html source of `:index` action from the action `:process_img`. Need to access that code in controller.

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end

  def process_img
    index_html_code = "the html source of index action should be here"
  end
end
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try `render_to_string`? https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal  no that doesn't help cause I'm getting Missing template error , but I have that template in my app.

Comment: @AjinkyaPisal fixed the issue now works! Thanks!

Comment: glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `render_to_string` (renders according to the same rules as render, but returns the result in a string instead of sending it as the response body to the browser):

```
render_to_string :index
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `Template is missing
Missing template home/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:jpeg], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/kmanuk/projects/ruby_on_rails/ponies/app/views" * "/Users/kmanuk/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
`   but I have that template in place.

Comment: @arm2pro the layout for `index` action for your `home` controller should be placed in `views/home/index`. If you have another path, you can also specify a path, not only action, e.g., `render_to_string 'landing/index'`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think `render_to_string` is an idiomatic option here's a way to do it which would work in plain ruby as well:

```
ERB.new(File.read "app/views/home/index.html.erb").result binding
```

Comment: How can I render that file without layout file ?

Comment: That's exactly what this will do

Comment: Sorry I'd like to say I need it render with layout :(